# Relation error in yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, relational-database

I am new to `yii`. I have three models models

```
 Site(id,name)
 User(id,name,..)
 UserSite(id,user_id,site_id)
```

What i need is when im selecting a dropdown of site I need to users belongs to that site

the relation in User model is 
   `'userSites' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'UserSite', 'id'),`

And the search function User model is,

```
public function search($sid)
    {
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('customer_id',$this->customer_id,true);
        $criteria->compare('email',$this->email,true);
        $criteria->compare('password',$this->password,true);
        $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
        $criteria->compare('company',$this->company,true);
        $criteria->compare('country',$this->country,true);
        $criteria->compare('date_added',$this->date_added,true);
                $criteria->compare('expiry_date',$this->expiry_date,true);
                if($sid!=null)
                {
                    $criteria->with = array('userSites'); 
                    $criteria->addCondition('userSites.site_id='.$sid);
                }

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,

        ));
    }
```

Here what happenning is displaying users like `(user.id=user_site.id)` but actually i need `(user.id=user_site.user_id)`.

Now this relation `'userSites' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'UserSite', 'id'),`returns `UserSite->id` what i need it has to return `UserSite->User_id`

Please Somebody help me to solve this problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relation is inverted. Each `User` can have many `UserSite`s therfore your relation should be

```
'userSites' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserSite', 'user_id')
```

To eager load relations in `CActiveDataProvider` you have to set [`CDbCriteria::together`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#together) to `true`:

```
if($sid!=null){
    $criteria->together = true;
    ...
```

An explanation for this is given at http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/280/1-n-relations-sometimes-require-cdbcriteria-together/

> But tracing the application's queries shows that when CActiveDataProvider gets data, it handles 1:n related tables a bit different. AR gets the data from the parent table and 1:1 related child tables with one query joining all those 1:1 child tables. 1:n child tables are not part of this query. AR gets data from those with subsequent queries, one query per 1:n child table, specifying the rows it wants with a WHERE PK IN (id1, id2, ...) clause.

Comment: I have already tried that at that time its getting error CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'userSites.site_id' in 'where clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`customer_id` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`email` AS `t0_c2`, `t`.`password` AS `t0_c3`, `t`.`name` AS `t0_c4`, `t`.`company` AS `t0_c5`, `t`.`country` AS `t0_c6`, `t`.`date_added` AS `t0_c7`, `t`.`expiry_date` AS `t0_c8` FROM `user` `t` WHERE (userSites.site_id=4) LIMIT 100